# Exception in ASGI application Of FastAPI

Tags: fastapi

I'm using FastAPI and the following error is reported, but I don't know where the error is when I'm tracing.

I have read this link, but it's no use:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830284/fastapi-and-pydantic-recursionerror-causing-exception-in-asgi-application
```

```
[2021-03-31 14:47:51 +0800] [24970] [WARNING] Invalid HTTP request received.
[2021-03-31 14:47:54 +0800] [24965] [WARNING] Invalid HTTP request received.
[2021-03-31 18:12:53 +0800] [24970] [ERROR] Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 390, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 179, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 86, in __call__
    await self.simple_response(scope, receive, send, request_headers=headers)
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 142, in simple_response

repeat more times......uitil:

  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/facli-zsB1kvQc-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 74, in __call__
    headers = Headers(scope=scope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/typing.py", line 869, in __new__
    if cls in (Generic, Protocol):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: The error says everything what one can say, given the stacktrace maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison . Are you sure you don't have a recursive function that calls itself by accident?

Comment: I'll start with a comprehensive follow-up